# What is the quickest way to create a new collection that contains the contents of another collection plus one more element

Tags: java, collections

For java 7/8:

If I have two collections, a and b where both are collections of strings, I am hoping to find is the most time-efficient way of creating a new collection for each element in b that will contain all of the elements in a plus the current element in b.

Example input:

```
a = [a,b,c,d]
b = [e,f,g]
```

Example output:

```
[
    [a,b,c,d,e],
    [a,b,c,d,f],
    [a,b,c,d,g]
]
```

I understand how to do this with streams and collect, and I know how to do this with a for loop and building collections, but I want to know if there is a faster way to do this.  I have the logic worked out, and now I am attempting to optimize for speed *because we really need it*!

Comment: do you want to create new collection with common elements in `a` and `b` ?

Comment: No.  As I was saying above, it should be *all* of the elements of a, plus *one* element in b for every element in b.  That should result in b.size() * collections.

Comment: can you provide an example input output please?

Comment: For such tasks, you should never ask for time-efficiency, but for code readability. A simple `List<String> list = new ArrayList(a); list.add(current);` should be enough (assuming `current` holds the current string of the `b` collection).

Comment: If I got the question right, he wants for each element B in b to create a new collection which has all elements of a plus B.

Comment: "a plus the current element in b"  Do you mean concatenate each element?

Comment: I updated the question with example input and output.

Comment: I am curious about why someone down-voted the question.  If I could improve it, please leave a comment and let me know how and why.  I think that questions regarding performance are legitimate and useful.  If the down-vote regards clarity, I have endeavored to make it more clear with an example.  If it regards research, I indicated that I can get it to work with for-each and streams.  So, what's the gripe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use streams to solve this problem, collecting a `List<List<Integer>>`.

Here is a possible solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
    List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
    List<List<Integer>> collect = b.stream().map(e -> Stream.concat(a.stream(), Stream.of(e)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

This will print out:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```

The advantage of using streams is that you can easily parallelize it and this might boost your performance in case of large datasets.

Comment: This is approximately as performant as: new ArrayList<>(a); list.add(bElement);

Comment: This is pretty clear and concise.  So far, I cannot find anything to perform better, so I will accept this as the answer.  Thank you for helping me.